# add pallet_assets error: ^^^ Config not found in 'pallet_assets'

Tags: runtime, substrate

I get this error when trying to compile and I seem to be unable to solve it...:

In terminal, after running 'cargo check' I get:

```
Compiling node-template-runtime v2.0.1 (/runtime)
  error[E0405]: cannot find trait `Config` in crate `pallet_assets`
     --> /runtime/src/lib.rs:360:21
      |
  360 | impl pallet_assets::Config for Runtime {
      |                     ^^^^^^ not found in `pallet_assets`

  error: aborting due to previous error...
```

I tried with 'Trait' instead of Config, but throws even more errors...?

A hint would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Which version of the assets pallet are you using? would be good to post more details so that it is reproducible.

Comment: yes it was a version issue (as detailed below also). thank you anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Config` trait was introduced in version 3.0.0 of substrate. As you pointed out, it was previously `Trait`. It is only expected for any substrate project to be compile-able if you use all of the *same major version* (2.x or 3.x) for building. I highly recommend using v3+ from now on, v2 is not expected to be supported moving forward.